# How to put 2 logic block in same async route in nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have a post route which calls a service and has a .catch handler to handle any errors, also the code itself has try - catch block. But when I'm trying to call another service only of first service callback value is not desired, it shows following errors. Eg. Await cannot be used outside async, or when it goes to condition 2, app crashes. Here's the structure-

```
router.post('/Students', async(req,res) => {
try{
...
studentService(req.body). then ((res)=>{
....// if res.body == 'Student'
.....
res.send(res.body)
}
})
.catch(error){
....
}
catch(err){
....
}
}

module.exports = router
```

Now how can I check that if res.body!='Student' or the studentService fails, then go to second block which calls another service and has it's own error handler.(Note- It executes only if first one is false or desired value not obtained)

Not sure where and how to place it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `asynce` in your example code is a typo.

Inside an async function you can use await rather than .then().

Also, it's probably best if you don't overwrite your route's `res` with the output from your studentService.

And, in a route you must do *something* in all cases.  Send a result, throw an error, send an error, whatever.  The `else` side of your `if` doesn't do anything in your sample.

You can throw an error by calling express's `next()` with a parameter.

So try this.

```js
const createError = require('http-errors')

...

router.post('/Students', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    ...
    const student = await studentService(req.body)
    if (student.body === 'Student') {
      ...
      return res.send(student.body)
    }
  catch (error) {
     return next(error)
  }
  try {
    const something = await someOtherService(req.body)
    if (something.whatever === 'Underpaid Adjunct Faculty') {
      return res.send(something.body)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error)
  }
  return next(createError(400, 'Got an error'))
}

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. Yup, asynce was a typo